# JS Alert or append is not working on DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, weather-api

Please look at this code on https://jsfiddle.net/safron6/9g98j68g/embedded/result/

I am trying to get the calculated result from the list of APIS and JSON code that is generated to show the precipIntensity. At the end of the code there is an alert and the code works in firebug but nothing is showing up. What may be the reason why the alert does not pop up?

```
var listAPIs = "";

$.each(threeDayAPITimes, function(i, time) {
    var darkForecastAPI= "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + currentAPIKey + "/" + locations + "," + time +"?callback=?"; 
     $.getJSON(darkForecastAPI, {
        tags: "WxAPI[" + i + "]",  //Is this tag the name of each JSON page? I tried to index it incase this is how to refer to the JSON formatted code from the APIs.
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    }, function(result) {
        // Process the result object    
        var eachPrecipSum = 0;
    if(result.currently.precipIntensity >=0 && result.currently.precipType == "rain")
        {
            $.each(result, function() {
              eachPrecipSum += (result.currently.precipIntensity);
              totalPrecipSinceDate += eachPrecipSum ;  ///Write mean precip
                        alert(eachPrecipSum );
                        $("body").append("p").text(eachPrecipSum)
        });

        }   
    });
```

Comment: You should probably URL encode the data you're inserting into the URL

Comment: hmmm. I was just thinking that JSON might be why... the if statement may be saying no there is nothing like this so do nothing.

Comment: Well, I don't know, I don't have a valid API key, so I'm just getting `403 forbidden` and can't test this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

totalPrecipSinceDate did not declared.

Answer (score 0):

I can't access your hosted data source.

Replacing your current `$.getJSON` call with an `$.ajax` call should work:

```
$.each(threeDayAPITimes, function(i, time) {
var darkForecastAPI= "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + currentAPIKey + "/" + locations + "," + time +"?callback=?"; 

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: darkForecastAPI,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
      var eachPrecipSum = 0;
      if(result.currently.precipIntensity >=0 && result.currently.precipType == "rain") {
        $.each(result, function() {
          eachPrecipSum += (result.currently.precipIntensity);
          totalPrecipSinceDate += eachPrecipSum ;  ///Write mean precip
          alert(eachPrecipSum );
          $("body").append("p").text(eachPrecipSum)
        });
      }
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('failure');
    }
  });
});
```